# Нужно скорректировать правильно код телеграмм бота на пайтоне

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот, telebot

Нужно что бы функции выполнялись последовательно, а у меня после получения фамилии, постоянно выводится /reg

```
import telebot

name = '';
surname = '';

bot = telebot.TeleBot("1119574263:AAEAj7XVzpHLVHPNnLs_9TrHvITraba9PnY")

keyboard1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
keyboard1.row('Заказать стикеры', 'Связаться со мной')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):
    if message.text == '/reg':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Как тебя зовут?", reply_markup=keyboard1);
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_name); #получаем имя
    else:   
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Напиши /reg');

def get_surname(message):
    surname = message.text
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, send_text);

def get_name(message): #получаем фамилию
    global name;
    name = message.text;
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Какая у тебя фамилия? После нажмите заказать стикеры.');
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_surname);

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text == 'Заказать стикеры': #далее пользователь нажимает на кнопку заказать стикеры и выводится это
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ' Для заказа введите ваши данные (Имя Фамилия, Телефонный номер, Адрес)')
    elif message.text == 'Связаться со мной':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=77086836315')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def send_photo(message): #и в самом конце бот переотправляет мне отправленную фотографию
    bot.forward_message(474551257, message.chat.id, message.message_id)

bot.polling()
```

Comment: Возможно [вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1108130/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-bot-r) похожи, посмотрите это решение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1108170/234134

Answer (score 1):

Сделай отдельно обработчики команд

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def start(message):
   bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введи /reg  для регистрауии")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['reg'])
def reg(message):
   bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Как тебя зовут?")
   bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_name)
```

Также советую использовать инлайн клавиатуру.
Это и удобнее и есть обработчик отдельный.

К каждой кнопке клавиатуры добавляешь значение `callback_data`.
Потом просто обрабатываешь значения и текст. 
У тебя не будет винегрета с текстом от юзера

```
key.add(item_i0, item_i1)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'order'
```

и тут уже можешь текст обрабатывать

Вот здесь про клаву почитать можешь:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup

И еще, зарегай нового бота, ты засветил токен, сейчас кто угодно может данные получить.