# Как вызвать ряд функций из модуля в основной файл проекта с использованием bot.register_next_step_handler

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня есть 2 файла. main.py - основа проекта и reg.py - регистрация пользователя.
reg.py

```
from telebot import types
import telebot, requests

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')
user_data = {}
class User_register:
    def __init__(self, login):
        self.login = login
        self.password = " "
        self.email = " "
        self.category = " "


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_login(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=False)
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите логин: ", reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, send_password)


def send_password(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user_data[user_id] = User_register(message.text)
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите пароль: ")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, send_email)


def send_email(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user = user_data[user_id]
    user.password = message.text
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите email: ")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, send_category)


def send_category(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user = user_data[user_id]
    user.email = message.text

    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    itembtn1 = types.KeyboardButton('ИС-16')
    itembtn2 = types.KeyboardButton('ИС-17')
    itembtn3 = types.KeyboardButton('ИС-18')
    itembtn4 = types.KeyboardButton('ИС-19')

    markup.add(itembtn1, itembtn2, itembtn3, itembtn4)

    msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите Вашу группу: ", reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, last_process)


def last_process(message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user = user_data[user_id]
        user.category = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы успешно зарегистрированы.")
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Вы уже зарегистрированы.")


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

файл main.py

```
import telebot, logging, requests, json, time
from telebot import types
import reg

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')


def main_menu():
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(True)
    row = [types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Регистрация", callback_data="registration")]
    keyboard.row(*row)
    return keyboard


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def send_welcome(message):
    img = open("xxx", "rb")
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, img, caption="Добро пожаловать на платформу по обучению бездарей",
                   reply_markup=main_menu())


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_btn(call):
    data = call.data
    if data == "registration":
        reg.send_login(call.message)#первая функция в файле reg.py

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

В файле main.py я импортирую файл reg.py и мне нужно вызвать регистрацию пользователя по нажатию кнопки.
Но если я указываю reg.send_login(message) и запускаю файл main.py то выполняться только 1 функция всей регистрации и не переходит на следующий шаг. Как мне сделать что бы при вызове функции он проходил по всем шагам??

Comment: Сделайте пожалуйста пример воспроизводимым: приведите два минимальных листинга для main.py и для reg.py. Сам токен конечно не нужно включать в код). В конце концов для телеграм ботов писали многие, но с использованием разных библиотек

Comment: @svmitin думаю так вам будет понятнее.

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['uiscreate'])
def uis_request_domain(message):
    if message.chat.id not in users_uis:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не дозволено')
    else:
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Создать сослуживца\nПочтовый ящикъ:\n'
                                             'example.ru')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(send, uis_request_data)


def uis_request_data(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'отмена':
       bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'На нетъ и суда нетъ')
       return
    global domain_uis
    domain_uis = message.text.lower()
    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите: ФИО должность нумер')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, create_uis)


def create_uis(message):
    first = message.text.split()[1]
    last = message.text.split()[0]
    middle = message.text.split()[2]
    phone = message.text.split()[4]
    position = message.text.split()[3]

    uis_login = create_nickname(first, last, middle, 'create_uis')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '✅ логинъ')

    uis_password = create_password()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '✅ шифръ')
```

вместо global можете воспользоваться [классом](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py)

Comment: Вы похоже не поняли что мне надо сделать.

Comment: Опишите вопрос подробнее, я постараюсь вам помочь

Comment: Мне нужно вызвать в файле main.py регистрацию пользователя которая описана в файле reg.py.
Я пишу в main, reg.send_login(message) после чего выполняется только первая функция, и не переходит на следующую

Comment: Добавил еще один ответ, так вы хотели?

Comment: Только вы все в один файл засунули, а я хотел что бы я импортировал файл reg в файл main

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def send_welcome(message):
    start_keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    start_registration = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Регистрация', callback_data='registration')
    start_keyboard.add(start_registration)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'привет', reply_markup=start_keyboard)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_btn(call):
    if call.data == "registration":
        send_login(call.message)


user_data = {}


class User_register:
    def __init__(self, login):
        self.login = login
        self.password = " "
        self.email = " "
        self.category = " "


def send_login(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=False)
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите логин: ", reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, send_password)


def send_password(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user_data[user_id] = User_register(message.text)
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите пароль: ")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, send_email)


def send_email(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user = user_data[user_id]
    user.password = message.text
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите email: ")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, send_category)


def send_category(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user = user_data[user_id]
    user.email = message.text

    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    itembtn1 = types.KeyboardButton('ИС-16')
    itembtn2 = types.KeyboardButton('ИС-17')
    itembtn3 = types.KeyboardButton('ИС-18')
    itembtn4 = types.KeyboardButton('ИС-19')

    markup.add(itembtn1, itembtn2, itembtn3, itembtn4)

    msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите Вашу группу: ", reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, last_process)


def last_process(message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user = user_data[user_id]
        user.category = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы успешно зарегистрированы.")
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Вы уже зарегистрированы.")


# Запуск бота
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Андрей, у меня возник подобный вопрос.
Из всех вариантов решения, я предполагаю, что надо как-то правильно применять

```
if __name__=='__main__':
```

Так как вопрос был задан полтора года назад и если у вас получилось решить данную проблему, прошу дополнить вопрос.

Или можете ответить на странице [моего вопроса.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1348281/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83)
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у вас есть другие вопросы, вы можете задать их нажав кнопку «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Дополнительно вы можете [добавить вознаграждение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), чтобы привлечь к вопросу больше внимания, когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет достаточного уровня. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/670673)