# Как импортировать в основной файл модули нескольких побочных? Выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Всех приветствую!
Подскажите, как правильно сделать:
1.Есть основной файл Main.py, в нём хранится меню бота с Reply клавиатурой и импортированы 3 нижеуказанных файла (для перевода в них с нажатия после выбора какого-то пункта в меню):

```
import Config 
import Cycle_a
import Cycle_b

bot = telebot.TeleBot(Config.Token_Bot)
```

2.Есть Config.py, в нём хранится сам Token_Bot.
3.Есть Cycle_а.py, в нём пошаговый бот с анкетой. Вызов токена бота осуществляется так и везде где:

```
from Main import bot
```

4. Есть Cycle_b.py, в нём другой пошаговый бот. Вызов токена осуществляется аналогично вышеуказанному.

По отдельности файлы работают, при совмещении Main.py и Cycle_a.py все тоже нормально (с меню переводит на анкету). Но когда совмещаю все три файла выдаёт ошибку:

> cannot import name 'bot' from partially initialized module 'Main'
> (most likely due to a circular import) (---путь----\Main.py) File
> "---путь---\Cycle_a.py", line 8, in  from Main import bot File
> "---путь---\Main.py", line 12, in  import Cycle_a File
> "---путь----\Cycle_b.py", line 9, in  from Main import bot
> File  "---путь----\Main.py", line 11, in  import Cycle_b

Как я понимаю, что у меня как-то не так реализован вызов бота с основного файла во все остальные и  при запуске все вызывают одного бота.
Совмещать все в один код не очень хотелось бы, желательно вообще вызов бота перенести в Config, но возникнет та же проблема.

Подскажите, как можно сделать по другому или исправить это же?
Заранее благодарен.

P.S. Пишу на Python, библиотека TelegramBotApi

**Дополняю кодом основными частями кода, где вызываю файлы:**

Main.py

```
import Config 
import Cycle_a
import Cycle_b

bot = telebot.TeleBot(Config.Token_Bot)


def menu_step(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add('Анкета 1', 'Анкета 2')
    markup.add('Обратная связь')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери ниже', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def menu_two_step(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'анкета 1': 
        null_anketa_step(message)
    if message.text.lower() == 'анкета 2': 
        null_anketass_step(message)
```

Cicle_a.py

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import sqlite3
import Main.py
#from Main.py import bot #Пробовал так для обращения к боту.
from Config import Group_id

user_data = {}

class User:
    def __init__(self, datas):
        self.datas = datas
        self.datass = ''

conn = sqlite3.connect('DataBase.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()

def db_table_val(user_id: int, dataone: str, datatwo: str):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO datatable (user_id, dataone, datatwo) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (user_id, dataone, datatwo))
    conn.commit()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['anketaone'])
def null_anketa_step(message):
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите данные №1")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_one_step)

def process_one_step(message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user_data[user_id] = User(message.text)
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите данные №2')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_two_step)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка')

def process_two_step(message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user = user_data[user_id]
        user_data[user_id] = User(message.text)
        db_table_val(user_id=user_id, dataone=user.datas, datatwo=user.datass)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы успешно ввели все данные')
    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка')
        bot.send_message(Group_id, 'У вас новая анкета!')
 

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

В Cycle_b.py аналогично, просто вопросы другие и чуть больше.

==========================**ДОПОЛНЯЮ**=============================

1. Добавил в конце каждого скрипта

   if **name**=='**main**':
   bot.polling(none_stop=True)
2. Убрал в Cycle_a.py и Cycle_b.py:

   from Main import bot
3. Соответственно в каждом файле добавил токен бота:

   bot = telebot.TeleBot(Config.Token_Bot)

Теперь все запускается без ошибки, при нажатии Анкета 1 -> запускается скрипт из побочного файла -> Выдаёт "Введите данные №1, но на следующий шаг не переводит. Ошибок никаких нет, можно даже опять вызвать меню. Просто не хочет переводить на следующий шаг.

Answer (score 1):

главное что он пишет это

> most likely due to a circular import

т.е. вы из Main.py импортируете ваши import Cycle_*.py которые сами в свою очередь пытаются импортировать Main.py. Т.е. у вас по логике они бесконечное количество раз пытаются друг-друга загрузить, т.е. зацикливаются.

Как этого избежать однозначного ответа нет - надо смотреть код

Comment: Из Main.py я использую импорт только для перевода из меню.
Т.е. пользователь нажимает клавишу и обработчик переводит в Cycle_*.py:
`@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def anketa_step(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'Анкета 1': 
        Cycle_a.null_anketa_step(message)`
В файлах Cycle_*.py я импортирую только для токена.

`from Cycle_a import null_anketa_step` тоже не сработал

Comment: дополните ваш вопрос минимально воспроизводимым примером и сообщество вам обязательно поможет. по комментариям эти вещи диагностировать нереально

Comment: Сергей, дополнил основной вопрос примером кода.

Comment: в Cycle_registration и Config есть импорты?

Comment: Исправил код, там на самом деле он обращался к Main.py. Cycle_b обращается тоже к Main.py.  А в главный файл импортированы оба Cycle_*, для перехода при нажатии пользователем. Также в Cycle_* импортирован Config, где лежит id группы в которую приходит оповещение, но это, мне кажется, не влияет.

Comment: В Config импортов нет, там пока что только токен и id группы

Comment: Дополнил вопрос